# Java: MultiThread Synchronization, causing deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create two threads **OddThread** and **EvenThread** which prints odd number and even number respectively. I've tried to sync those two threads to print natural numbers.

It is working fine but i don't know why it is getting into deadlock after sometime.

My code looks like this:

```
public class NaturalNoPrint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object lock = new Object();
        Thread oddThread = new Thread(new OddThread(lock));
        Thread evenThread = new Thread(new EvenThread(lock));
        oddThread.start();
        evenThread.start();
    }
}

class OddThread implements Runnable{
    private int no=1;
    private Object lock;

    OddThread(Object lock){
        this.lock=lock;
    }
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            synchronized(lock){
                try {           
                    lock.wait();
                    System.out.println(no);
                    no+=2;
                    lock.notify();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);         
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class EvenThread implements Runnable{
    private int no=2;
    private Object lock;

    EvenThread(Object lock){
        this.lock=lock;
    }
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            synchronized(lock){
                try{            
                    lock.notify();
                    lock.wait();
                    System.out.println(no);
                    no+=2;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help to to identify the cause of deadlock.

Comment: When do you see deadlock? Note that `sleep` does not release ownership of monitors.

Comment: Both threads are just going to wait forever to be notified. Who's gonna notify them?

Comment: When i run this program, it prints correctly sometime up to 10 natural numbers sometimes up to 4 natural numbers.

Comment: @JasonCoco But initially it is printing the sequence. I tried to wake up one thread by another. Why you think, both will wait forever? Can you please explain?

Comment: remove all lock.notify and lock.wait for getting out of dead lock. Read for more ref http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my modified code with semaphore which is working fine:

```
public class NaturalNoPrint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore oddMutex = new Semaphore(0);
        Semaphore evenMutex = new Semaphore(0);
        Thread oddThread = new Thread(new OddThread(oddMutex,evenMutex));
        Thread evenThread = new Thread(new EvenThread(oddMutex,evenMutex));
        evenThread.start();
        oddThread.start();
    }
}

class OddThread implements Runnable{
    private int no=1;
    private Semaphore oddMutex,evenMutex;
    OddThread(Semaphore oddMutex,Semaphore evenMutex){
        this.oddMutex=oddMutex;
        this.evenMutex=evenMutex;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            //synchronized(lock){
                try {           
                    //lock.wait();
                    oddMutex.acquire();
                    System.out.println(no);
                    no+=2;
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                    //lock.notify();
                    evenMutex.release();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            //}
        }
    }
}


class EvenThread implements Runnable{
    private int no=2;
    //private Object lock;
    private Semaphore oddMutex,evenMutex;

    EvenThread(Semaphore oddMutex,Semaphore evenMutex){
        this.oddMutex=oddMutex;
        this.evenMutex=evenMutex;
    }
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            //synchronized(lock){
                try{            
                    //lock.notify();
                    //lock.wait();
                    oddMutex.release();
                    evenMutex.acquire();
                    System.out.println(no);
                    no+=2;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks **Sotirios Delimanolis** and other members for helping me to find out the root cause..

Answer (score 4):

You have a race condition.

If the scheduler schedules `EvenThread` first, it synchronizes on `lock` and immediately calls `notify`, releasing the monitor. The `OddThread` then acquires the `lock` monitor and calls `wait()` which releases the monitor but does not `notify` the `EvenThread`. Both threads are now waiting for a `notify` that will never come.

This can happen at any point during execution and is up to the `Thread` scheduler.

Comment: Can you please suggest a way to get out of this race condition?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the scenario for a dead lock:

```
OddThread:  waits 
EvenThread: notifies 
OddThread:  prints, notifies (EvenThread is not waiting yet! - here is the problem) 
OddThread:  waits 
EvenThread: waits
```

Comment: What can i do to make sure that thread is notified if it is waiting otherwise it should not notify? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It's quite a challenging task to make this 100% working with `wait()` and `notify()`, because i.e. `wait()` can spontaneously break. Can you use other idioms or additional conditions like `volatile` variables?

Comment: I checked with `Semaphore`, it worked fine. I'll try to do this with your suggestion (using `volatile` variables). Thanks.